Documentation for nftables
I've been migrating from "higher level" (awall, ufw, firewall-cmd, etc.) firewall tools to nftables "scripts", but the documentation experience hasn't been the best. The man pages & nftables wiki (and other sources like Gentoo & Arch wiki, Ubuntu & Debian man pages, etc.) don't seem to cover everything.
For example "meta l4proto", I've found on the Gentoo wiki that it can accept "ipv6-icmp" to check for v6 pings, but this is only shown in an example, and not documented anywhere else.
The man pages only provide:



l4proto
layer 4 protocol, skips ipv6 extension headers
integer (8 bit)



Another example is the "meta" expression keyword itself. There are examples of matches that use it and matches that don't (eg: meta iff foo vs iff foo). So, is it simply a "verbosity" thing? or does it change the behaviour/matching of the rule?
From the man pages:

There are two types of meta expressions: unqualified and qualified meta expressions. Qualified meta expressions require the meta keyword before the meta key, unqualified meta expressions can be specified by using the meta key directly or as qualified meta expressions.

As such, while I could hack together firewalls from different sources (mostly examples seem to be the most informative), it all seems very counter-productive and I don't feel confident enough to deploy nftables I don't understand in production. Is there an actual complete source that covers nftables?
I've looked at nftables as generated by the "high level" firewall tools, and they all seem to use very mixed styles.
Annexed a script I played around with:
#!/usr/bin/nft -f

flush ruleset

table inet my {
    set CloudflareDNSv4 {
        type ipv4_addr
        elements = {1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1}
    }

    set CloudflareDNSv6 {
        type ipv6_addr
        elements = {2606:4700:4700::1111, 2606:4700:4700::1001}
    }

    chain MY_INPUT {
        type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;

        ct state invalid drop

        meta l4proto icmp counter jump PING
        meta l4proto ipv6-icmp counter jump PING

        ct state established,related accept

        meta iif "lo" accept
        meta iif != "lo" ip  daddr 127.0.0.1/8 drop
        meta iif != "lo" ip6 daddr ::1/128 drop

        tcp dport 22 accept

        log prefix "IN Dropped packet: " drop
        counter
    }

    chain MY_FORWARD {
        type filter hook forward priority 0; policy drop;

        log prefix "FW Dropped packet: " drop
        counter
    }

    chain MY_OUTPUT {
        type filter hook output priority 0; policy drop;

        ct state established,related accept
        ct state invalid drop

        meta oif "lo" accept
        meta oif != "lo" ip  saddr 127.0.0.1/8 drop
        meta oif != "lo" ip6 saddr ::1/128 drop

        udp dport  53 jump DNS
        udp dport 853 jump DNS

        meta l4proto icmp accept
        meta l4proto ipv6-icmp accept

        log prefix "OUT Dropped packet: " drop
        counter
    }

    chain DNS {
        ip  daddr @CloudflareDNSv4 accept
        ip6 daddr @CloudflareDNSv6 accept

        drop
    }

    chain PING {
        counter packets 0 bytes 0
        limit rate over 10/second burst 5 packets drop

        icmp type {
            echo-reply,                 # 0
            destination-unreachable,    # 3
            echo-request,               # 8
            time-exceeded,              # 11
            parameter-problem,          # 12
        } accept
        icmpv6 type {
            destination-unreachable,    # 1
            packet-too-big,             # 2
            time-exceeded,              # 3
            parameter-problem,          # 4
            echo-request,               # 128
            echo-reply,                 # 129
        } accept

        drop
    }
}

